# How can I read the id of a component in tapestry decorator? Or validate a checkbox

Tags: validation, checkbox, decorator, tapestry

I have a custom validation decorator. In the method "public void afterLabel(Field field)" I can't get the id of the component. I tried field.getClientId() and field.getControlName(), but they are always null. In the component I did this:

```
<input t:type="Checkbox" t:id="requiredOwner" t:value="currentVehicle.owner" t:clientId="requiredOwner" />
```

My question is, how can I validate a checkbox with tapestry5; or how can I access the id of the field inside the decorator.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[This might help.](http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/input/novalidationbubbles1) It looks like you may have to defer the code that uses the id using the heartbeat.

```
public void afterLabel(Field field) {
    Runnable command = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        String fieldId = field.getClientId();
        ...
      }
    };
    heartbeat.defer(command);
}
```